# Using vs 2013 express when running my program i'm getting message: symbols for module were not loaded, how can i fix it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

It started to show this message few minutes ago not sure why.

When i start my program i see the message i click ok then it keep loading my program and run it fine.

[image: Symbols]

I didn't find 1 and 2 and how to do it.

Why this message show up at all ? How can i remove this thing so it won't show any more ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Project properties > Build > Advanced... > Debug info: full

The Debug info was set to: none
Once changed it to full everything is working.